# What is a Geo Cookie? How do I implement one?

Tags: html, cookies

I've been tasked with using a 'Geo Cookie' to identify where in the world users are accessing the site from, and to redirect them to a site configured for their region.

I understand what a cookie is in the context of the web, but I'm not sure about a geo cookie, partly because I've never heard of one before.

Could somebody please tell me if this a real thing, or if it could be a term that was made up by people who didn't know the proper name for what they're really talking about? (this happens quite regularly, it seems). Is there any way for me to identify where the user is located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd never heard of the term before, and doing a [little googling](http://www.google.com/#q=geo+cookie) confirmed my suspicion that this is not a common term in usage.

My thoughts, [reading off of the first search result from that query](http://valleywag.gawker.com/5034896/how-to-crack-youtubes-olympics-channel), is that you're being asked to implement a cookie that stores the users region. This can be done with a normal cookie, and you can give it the name "GEO" - viola! A Geo Cookie.

If I were you, I'd go back to the stakeholder and find out what this requirement means.

---

For determining where a user is located (without asking the directly) you can use the ip of the user, and a geo-location service.  See [Know a good IP address Geolocation Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283016/know-a-good-ip-address-geolocation-service) for more info on that.

Answer (score 0):

A geo cookie is just a cookie which you store the geo data in.

This allows you to:

- Avoid having to hit the geo/ip database with each request
- Allow users to override the location (e.g. I know it looks like I'm in Spain, and as it happens, I am (yay holidays), but I want data for England, that is where I live, and that is where I want my results localised to).